# Is this a new deterministic primality test???

Tags: primality-test

$|(x-1)^p -(x^p-1)-(x^{p-1} -2)| \equiv -1 \mod p$

It seems to work. Can anyone refute it or improve it?

Comment: What seems to work?

Comment: I don't have many comments about my formula. Can anyone show me why it works??

Comment: What is the test?

Comment: The first line congruent to -1 mod p

Comment: $x$ is undefined.

Comment: X>2 and doesn't divide p

Comment: So $x$ is a particular value or is this meant to hold for all $x$?  What's the point of making your readers guess what you are talking about?  Write out the test in full.

Comment: the test is the first line iff p is prime

Comment: it should hold for all x >2

Comment: Your formula is obviously wrong for, say, $x=2p$.  Presumably you meant to exclude that, but who knows?  Please edit your question to write out the test in full detail.

Comment: Voting to close the question as it is not clear what you are asking.  If you can, please edit your post to explain your test in full and clear detail.  It should be straightforward to show that it holds if $p$ is in fact a prime, usually the difficulty is the other direction,   You might want to include the proof of the easy direction as well.

Answer (score 3):

$(x-1)^p -(x^p-1)-(x^{p-1} -2)$ is negative for positive $x$. Thus (I will assume $p $ is prime and will use Fermat's little theorem):

$$\begin{align}& |(x-1)^p -(x^p-1)-(x^{p-1} -2)| \\ =&-(x-1)^p +(x^p-1)+(x^{p-1} -2) \\  \equiv & -(x-1)+(x-1)+x^{p-1}-2 \\ = & x^{p-1}-2 \\ \equiv & -2+\begin {cases}0 & p|x \\ 1 & \text{otherwise}\end {cases} \\ =& \begin {cases}-2 & p|x \\ -1 & \text{otherwise}\end {cases}\end {align}$$

so your formula holds for $x\gt 0, x\not\equiv 0\pmod p $.

**Notes**:

- The formula doesn't hold for negative $x $, fix it by removing the modulus and just putting the minus sign in front.
- There is a lot of overhead: no need to calculate $(x-1)^p $ and $x^p-1$ when they will cancel each other.
- Why take away 2 to get -1 when you can *not* take away 2 and get... well... 1?

In other words, your test boils down to: $x^{p-1}\equiv 1\pmod p $ if $p\not|x $. This is a well-known result (Fermat's little theorem proves one side, and for a composite number the test fails for any proper divisor $x\ne 1$ of $p $). Caveat: I didn't look at how *your* test behaves for composite $p $ - it may well *succeed*...

As a practical *primality test*, this requires testing every number $x$ in the range $[2,p-2] $, so is grossly inefficient. If you are already iterating in that range - why not check directly if $x|p $ or not?